# How to create postgres user/role if not exists using python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am creating postgresql server user/role using python. In this condition if user already exits means print error, if not exist means create user/role in postgres. I have tried below code its not working. The same way I have achieved DB Creation. Request you suggestion.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT
## root user connection
def userCreation():    
    con = psycopg2.connect(
          user='root', host='127.0.0.1', port = '5432', 
          password='root')
    con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
    cur = con.cursor()
    ## New User/Role Creation
    try:
        username = input("Enter User Name : ")
        pwd = input("Enter Password : ")
        cur.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE  rolname = "+username+";").format(sql))
        print ("User Already Exist..!")
    except:
        cur.execute(sql.SQL("CREATE ROLE"+username+"  LOGIN PASSWORD"+pwd+";").format(sql))
        print ("DB User has been created Successfully ..!")
```

Comment: "its not working" is not enough. What happens or doesn't happen? Do you get an error?

Comment: @AKX Didn't receive an error.

Comment: But it just didn't do anything? That sounds unlikely.

Comment: `CREATE` is for creating tables. `INSERT` is for adding rows to existing tables.

Comment: @zvone `CREATE ROLE` is postgres. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-createrole.html

Comment: @AKX I see. I thought it was just a regular table with users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the trick for you.

- Don't use a bare `except:`, ever, it will hide all exceptions.
- Look at the query result to figure out whether rows were returned.
- If you are going to use `psycopg2.SQL()` to compose queries, you'll need to use it correctly
- Your code was vulnerable to SQL injection attacks because of that misuse.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql


def prompt_username(con):
    cur = con.cursor()
    while True:
        username = input("Enter User Name : ")
        cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE rolname = %s", [username])
        n, = cur.fetchone()
        if n == 0:
            return username
        print("User already exists.")


def userCreation():
    con = psycopg2.connect(
        user='postgres',
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port='5432',
        password='',
    )

    username = prompt_username(con)
    password = input(f"Enter Password for {username} : ")
    query = sql.SQL("CREATE ROLE {0} LOGIN PASSWORD {1}").format(
        sql.Identifier(username),
        sql.Literal(password),
    )
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query.as_string(con))
    cur.execute("COMMIT")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    userCreation()
```